# How to use the Keyword AUTOINCREMENT in SQLite for Android

Tags: android, sqlite, auto-increment

I would like to autoincrement an Integer ID value in one of my database tables using SQLiteOpenHelper for Android. So I have the following command:

```
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_RATINGS + " ("+ ID_RATING + " INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT , " + DRINK_NAME +" TEXT,  " + DRINK_STRENGTH +" TEXT ,  " + DRINK_SIZE + " TEXT , " + RATING_STARS + " INTEGER, " + EVALUATION_STRENGTH + " TEXT, " + EVALUATION_SWEETNESS + " TEXT, " + EVALUATION_COMMENT + " TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (" + ID_RATING + ")  ) ");
```

The ID_RATING should be an Integer that should be autoincremmented and it is the primary key. Without using the keyword 'AUTOINCREMENT' this lines works (but the ID is obviously not automatically incremented). But when using the keyword I get the following error message:

```
 '(', ')', <column constraint> or comma expected, got 'AUTOINCREMENT
```

Do you know how I can solve this problem? I'd appreciate every comment and will be thankful for your help.

Comment: What is the definition of ID_RATING?

Comment: Start by reading https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html and thinking about if you actually *need* what `AUTOINCREMENT` does. Your *but the ID is obviously not automatically incremented* bit is wrong, btw.

Comment: Then read https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html for the correct syntax.

Comment: Thhanks for all your answers forpas and Shawn. What I basically want is that the ID_RATING column should be automatically assigned an integer value and this value should be automatically incremented such that when inserting a row, the row get this ID_RATING value automatically

Comment: What is the actual name of the column ID_RATING?

Comment: Then all it needs is to be an `INTEGER` type and the `PRIMARY KEY`.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. The actunal name of the column is "public static final String ID_RATING = "ID_Rating";"

Comment: You must define the column as the PRIMARY KEY: `sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_RATINGS + " ("+ ID_RATING + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT ,......`. You may omit the keyword AUTOINCREMENT. Read the documentation in the links that Shawn provided for the difference between adding this keyword or not.

Comment: Thanks forpas. But I want to have the primary key definitions at the end of the statements because most often I have multiple primary keys. Is it also possible to use the keywork AUTOINCREMENT at the end of the line and it will just do what I want (new rows should get an automatic ID which is incremented successively)?

Comment: No, the correct syntax is `columnname INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT`

Comment: Ah okay, thanks Forpas. So I need to use AUTOINCREMENT direct after the PRIMARY KEY statement if I want the new rows to be automatically assigned a new ID. When using AUTOINCREMENT I do not have to specify the ID in the insert statement, right? I can just add the row without the ID and it will get the correct ID autmatically from SQLite.

Comment: Correct........

Comment: Thanks for your help forpas (and Shawn). I really appreciate it.